# De SQL a JSON - Arrays anidados

Tags: sql-server, json, jsonarray

Llevo unas horas aprendiendo por primera vez `SQL` y he llegado a una parte donde no encuentro el camino.

Lo que quiero es que a partir de una consulta `sql` de dos tablas relacionadas obtener un `json`, el caso es que por cada registro a la tabla 1 por cada fila le corresponden 8 filas de la tabla 2, quisiera que esas 8 filas fuesen un sub `array` dentro del `json`, esta seria la consulta para cada registro:

```
select Producto.Modelo, Producto.Descripcion, Especificacion.Descripcion, concat(Especificaciones.Valor,'  ',Especificacion.Unidad) Especificaciones 
from ProductoCatalogo as Producto 
inner join ProductoCatalogoEspecificacion as Especificaciones on Producto.ProductoCatalogoID = Especificaciones.ProductoCatalogoID
inner join Especificacion on Especificaciones.EspecificacionID = Especificacion.EspecificacionID 
where Producto.Modelo = 'HB02-100' for json auto
```

Esto es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el `json` que obtengo:

```
[
  {
    "Modelo": "HB02-100",
    "Descripcion": "Luminaria High Bay (UFO) Alta Eficiencia",
    "Especificacion": [
      {
        "Descripcion": "Potencia",
        "Especificaciones": "100  W"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Dimmable",
        "Especificaciones": "NO  "
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Tensión",
        "Especificaciones": "100~277  VCA"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Eficiencia",
        "Especificaciones": "150\/160  Lm\/W"
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Cantidad de leds",
        "Especificaciones": "240  "
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Protección",
        "Especificaciones": "IP66  "
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "Factor de Potencia",
        "Especificaciones": ">0,95  "
      },
      {
        "Descripcion": "C.R.I.",
        "Especificaciones": ">70  "
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Y este el que quisiera obtener:

```
[
  {
    "Modelo": "HB02-100",
    "Descripcion": "Luminaria High Bay (UFO) Alta Eficiencia",
    "Especificaciones": [
      {
        "Potencia": "100 W"
      },
      {
        "Dimmable": "NO"
      },
      {
        "Tensión": "100~277 VCA"
      },
      {
        "Eficiencia": "150/160 Lm/W"
      },
      {
        "Cantidad de leds": "240 "
      },
      {
        "Protección": "IP66 "
      },
      {
        "Factor de Potencia": ">0,95 "
      },
      {
        "C.R.I.": ">70 "
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Si tan solo publicaras los datos como texto.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias intentar algo como esto:

```
   select Producto.Modelo, 
   Producto.Descripcion, 
   (
     SELECT * 
     FROM Especificacion
     WHERE Especificacion.EspecificacionID = Especificaciones.EspecificacionID
     FOR JSON PATH
   ) as EspecificacionesProducto
  from ProductoCatalogo as Producto 
  inner join ProductoCatalogoEspecificacion as Especificaciones on 
  Producto.ProductoCatalogoID = Especificaciones.ProductoCatalogoID
  where Producto.Modelo = 'HB02-100' 
  for json auto
```

Ya que tienes que recorrer por cada registro de producto uno o más especificaciones, podrias anidar una consulta en formato json el cual te devolverá los datos pertenecientes al producto como una cadena de string

esto es lo que me retorna:

```
[
  {
    "Modelo": "HB02-100",
    "Descripcion": "Luminaria High Bay (UFO) Alta Eficiencia",
    "EspecificacionesProducto": [
      {
        "EspecificacionID": 1,
        "Descripcion": "Potencia",
        "Unidad": "W"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Modelo": "HB02-100",
    "Descripcion": "Luminaria High Bay (UFO) Alta Eficiencia",
    "EspecificacionesProducto": [
      {
        "EspecificacionID": 2,
        "Descripcion": "Dimmable"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Modelo": "HB02-100",
    "Descripcion": "Luminaria High Bay (UFO) Alta Eficiencia",
    "EspecificacionesProducto": [
      {
        "EspecificacionID": 3,
        "Descripcion": "Tensión",
        "Unidad": "VCA"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Modelo": "HB02-100",
    "Descripcion": "Luminaria High Bay (UFO) Alta Eficiencia",
    "EspecificacionesProducto": [
      {
        "EspecificacionID": 4,
        "Descripcion": "Eficiencia",
        "Unidad": "Lm\/W"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Modelo": "HB02-100",
    "Descripcion": "Luminaria High Bay (UFO) Alta Eficiencia",
    "EspecificacionesProducto": [
      {
        "EspecificacionID": 5,
        "Descripcion": "Cantidad de leds"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Modelo": "HB02-100",
    "Descripcion": "Luminaria High Bay (UFO) Alta Eficiencia",
    "EspecificacionesProducto": [
      {
        "EspecificacionID": 6,
        "Descripcion": "Protección"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Modelo": "HB02-100",
    "Descripcion": "Luminaria High Bay (UFO) Alta Eficiencia",
    "EspecificacionesProducto": [
      {
        "EspecificacionID": 7,
        "Descripcion": "Factor de Potencia"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Modelo": "HB02-100",
    "Descripcion": "Luminaria High Bay (UFO) Alta Eficiencia",
    "EspecificacionesProducto": [
      {
        "EspecificacionID": 12,
        "Descripcion": "C.R.I."
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Ya veo, intentemos entonces trasladar el inner join adentro de la consulta anidada, de esta forma:

```
 select Producto.Modelo, 
 Producto.Descripcion, 
  (
   SELECT * 
   FROM Especificacion
   inner join ProductoCatalogoEspecificacion as Especificaciones on 
   Producto.ProductoCatalogoID = Especificaciones.ProductoCatalogoID
   WHERE Especificacion.EspecificacionID = Especificaciones.EspecificacionID
   FOR JSON PATH
 ) as EspecificacionesProducto
from ProductoCatalogo as Producto 
where Producto.Modelo = 'HB02-100' 
for json auto
```

Comment: me sale este error: Msg 13605, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column expressions and data sources without names or aliases cannot be formatted as JSON text using FOR JSON clause. Add alias to the unnamed column or table.

Completion time: 2021-04-22T10:28:06.4736593-03:00

Comment: ponlo de esta forma para ver si te da,    (
     SELECT * 
     FROM Especificacion
     WHERE Especificacion.EspecificacionID = Especificaciones.EspecificacionID
     FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
   ) as EspecificacionesProducto

Comment: Tampoco funciona

Comment: Edite mi respuesta para que puedas ver el ejemplo completo, que version de SQL estas utilizando?

Comment: si bien ahora no da error al ejecutar la query los datos no vienen como esperaba, estoy usando sql server ultima version, lo instale ayer mismo desde microsoft.com. Gracias por tu tiempo!!

Comment: Traslade el inner join dentro de la consulta anidada, intenta verificar si te funciona, allí edite la respuesta para ser más claro el ejemplo

Comment: da este error, lo siento: Msg 13601, Level 16, State 1, Line 43
Property 'EspecificacionID' cannot be generated in JSON output due to a conflict with another column name or alias. Use different names and aliases for each column in SELECT list.

Comment: Verifica si en las tablas ProductoCatalogoEspecificacion  y Especificacion no contengan una columna del mismo nombre, en caso de que sea asi, te recomiendo que dentro de la sub consulta selecciones manualmente lo que necesitas mostrar, por ejemplo SELECT Especificacion.Descripcion, y asi sucesivamente en vez de llamar a todo el conjunto de datos con *